# IMAP high bandwith usage

Tags: email, imap, bandwidth, windows-live-mail

The bandwith usage for IMAP is rather high (6 GB monthly) while we are not sending a huge amount of email.

My email provider says this is caused by the fact that the email client checks the server for new email every second.

According to the provider, there should be a setting to lower the checking  frequency.

I have been looking at the server as well in the email client settings, but I cannot find such setting.

The client I have been checking is Windows LiveMail, but the IMAP is accessed by an Apple email client as well.

Anybody has any idea how to correct this?

Here is a part of the log:

> Aug 26 14:44:02 hostingxx dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=, method=PLAIN, rip=111.11.11.111, lip=111.11.111.111, mpid=1111, TLS, session=<123123123123>
>
> Aug 26 14:44:03 hostingxx dovecot: imap(xx@xx): Logged out in=1214, out=11726, bytes=1214/11726
>
> Aug 26 14:44:03 hostingxx dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=, method=PLAIN, rip=111.11.11.111, lip=111.11.111.111, mpid=5690, TLS, session=<123123123123>

Comment: You don't mention what client you are using.  Have you confirmed the client is checking for mail sever second?

Comment: Please, add more information about the server and client (product,version, etc.) to help people who wants to help you.